# SQL find a value from a column

Tags: sql

i have an easy question, imagine i have in a sql table a column A with values

```
    A

20.30.40
20.40
10.30
```

and so on.

I want to find all rows with just value 30 , how can i do that with a sql query ? its a string data column.
Please some help guys ..

Comment: There are no row with the value 30.

Comment: Is the expected output 20.30.40 and 10.30?

Comment: its a string data column !!

Comment: What's your point? Show your expected output of the query above. Are you wanting to return rows that equal '30' (and only '30') or do you want to return all rows that contain the value '30' anywhere in the string?

Comment: Do you want rows with 130 and 300 too?

Comment: thank you all but apomene  already answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, containing value 30, then:

```
select * from mytable where A like '%30%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LIKE` to find rows where the text `30` appears. Like so:

```
SELECT A FROM YOURTABLE WHERE A LIKE '%30%'
```